# Scale images within a table , and have them centered

Tags: css

I figured out how to get the images to scale within the table , but can't get anything to work to get them centered over the table.

set up demo here - 
https://jsfiddle.net/4m5vf9zb/

```css
td#divison00,
td#division01 {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.standingslogo {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I need to have them scalable , yet centered. Not sure if possible , and i don't have the authorization to change any existing HTML.

Answer (score 1):

My solution doesn't allow the images to scale beyond their native size but does center the images.

First step is to remove this CSS selector:

```css
td#divison00,
td#division01 {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Then remove `width: 100%;` from `.standingslogo`. Using `width: 100%;` forces the image to scale beyond it's native size (get all pixelated) and take up the full width of it's container (the `<td>`).

Next is to set the image to `display: block;` so it can use `margin: 0 auto;` for centering.

The final `.standingslogo` CSS selector should look like this:

```css
.standingslogo {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Your updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4m5vf9zb/1/

**EDIT**

With the two conditions set forth, *the images to have a max width of the containers size* and *never being larger then their native size*, I don't see a pure CSS solution. Adding `width: 100%;` to `.standingslogo` will get the images to scale within the table but then that breaks the second rule.

Comment: Thanks , i understand how to center the images without scaling them down. I need the images to have a max width of the containers size and be centered , while also never being larger then their native size.

but on mobile devices , since the images are user defined and can be very wide , i need them to scale down

Comment: This solution does allow the images to scale down. Did you check out the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4m5vf9zb/1/)? Not sure I understand the request _images to have a max-width of the containers size_. Are you concerned about the image overflowing it's container?

Comment: it doesn't work in Firefox or IE , your solution is only working in Chrome

Comment: I see that now. From what I can tell you might not be able to satisfy both your conditions. At least with a pure CSS solution. Adding `width: 100%;` to `.standingslogo` will get the images to scale within the table on FF and IE but that breaks the _never being larger then their native size_ condition. You might need a JS solution.